# How long does the airside shuttle take from Terminal A to Terminal C at Newark International?

Tags: connecting-flights, ewr

How long does it take to get from terminal A to C at Newark International on the airside shuttle? Arriving at Terminal A on United at 7:00 am and departing from Terminal C at 8:20 am on United. I am disabled and I walk with a cane. Some have suggested that I use the cart service but does that mean going through TSA again? I have no idea how long that would take. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newark Airport's terminal shuttles are placed outside of the security checkpoints so you have to leave the gate area to get onto the the shuttle and then go through TSA again.

Source: Source: https://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-airport-map.html
*Check out Terminal A and you can see on the gate level the icon for the shuttle and that it is before the security check point

It takes about 2 minutes in between each terminal so about 4 minutes for you from Terminal A to C and trains come every 3 minutes

[image: Source (scroll down to the second page): https://www.panynj.gov/airports/pdf/ewr-airtrain-brochure-english.pdf]

As for your cart question and having to go through TSA again, I'm not sure. When you check in with United you should ask them.

Edit: Specifically, if you wanted to stay airside you can look at Peter M's post for detailed information about that.

Comment: There's a different terminal shuttle inside the security checkpoint. AirTrain (the horrible awful no good train that breaks down when there's snow) runs outside security, which is what is shown on the map you've pasted. There's also a bus between the terminals that runs inside security. The OP will want to take the bus and stay in the secure area.

Answer (score 5):

[This map from United](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/maps/ewr.aspx) is the best overall map I have seen of Newark.
Then there is [the official airport map](https://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-airport-map.html).

From the United map you can see that the airside bus departs from terminal A2 and ends up on the right hand side of Terminal C.  From digging into the official map the bus seems to depart from near gate A28 in terminal A2, and arrives near gate C73 in terminal C

There is no mention that I can find of the duration and schedule of the airside bus.   However I did find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaWHriIhwMw) on youtube that is of the actual bus ride.  The video is only 1 minute 17 seconds long, but has been edited.  My best guess is that the trip itself is less than 10 minutes, and you could also be waiting for up to 10 minutes for the bus itself.

You mentioned cart services.  In the [accessibility part](https://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-accessibility-services.html) of the official airport site I found

> Electric Carts - Specially designed electric carts are available at
>   Terminal C for disabled passengers. These carts are available upon
>   request from your airline to transport you from the check-in area to
>   the ticket counter and then to the departure gate during operating
>   hours. For more information, please call your airline in advance.

Given the size of Terminal C it may make sense to try and book ahead at least for that part of your transfer - but I don't know if they will pick up up from the bus.  I am surprised that there is no mention of carts in any other terminal, but I would ask about Terminal A, as it seems to be a long way from either A1 or A3 to the bus departure point.

And there is no mention of Terminal to Terminal cart services.  But I think you are correct in that you would have to leave and reenter the secure areas - which would be something of a last resort to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I just took the bus inside security - hard to find by gate c71.  If coming in on international flight though you will probably still have to go through security again so might just take the train to correct terminal.