# 47 minute layover at Newark, is this doable?

Tags: usa, short-connections, united-airlines, ewr, pre-clearance

Searching for flights from Aruba to Ottawa, Canada using Expedia.com I run into this gem:

[image: Flight itinerary]

Is this doable?

Also, I read somewhere you could do US Immigration in Aruba, is this correct? (This would definitely simplify the process in Newark if it were so)

The flight would be the 20th if November, does this date coincide with high season or something in the US?

Comment: The 20th is the Tuesday before the US Thanksgiving holiday on Thursday. Wednesday is probably the heaviest travel day that week, but you should expect a lot of people on Tuesday too.

Comment: Good to know, thank you, will try to find a flight a few days earlier!

Comment: The weekend will be busy too. I saw an article from last year which said even the Friday before Thanksgiving week is busy.

Comment: Oh, ok gotcha. I was thinking one week earlier, nov 13th or so to get some distance from the holidays. Thank you mkennedy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aruba has pre-clearance so you go through customs and immigration in Oranjestad in Aruba before you board the plane and from there on it's basically a US domestic flight.

47 minutes is tight but doable if everything is on time and you have good mobility. EWR is a large airport, so there may quite a hike between gates.

If anything goes wrong or if there is even a minor delay, you'll miss it. United will still get you to Ottawa but it may only happen the next day. They may comp you for food or hotel (or they may not, the rules are complicated and not uniformly applied).

You need to decide whether you are ok with a potentially getting there a day later. If yes, go ahead an book it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and book it then, worst case I arrive a day after.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be leery of this one. The flight from Aruba will arrive in Terminal C, United's main terminal at Newark, while it looks like the flight to Ottawa often likes to leave from Terminal A (it did most days in the past week, but not all), where the United Express flights leave. There's [an airside shuttle bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107915/how-long-does-the-airside-shuttle-take-from-terminal-a-to-terminal-c-at-newark-i) that will get you there (**do not** exit the secure area and try to change terminals landside), but getting to the bus, waiting for the bus, riding the bus, and getting to your gate on the other side will take a while. Not inherently impossible, but way riskier than if you just had to walk to the next gate.

I'd consider alternatives and ensure you're prepared to cover the cost of a holiday week overnight stay in New York if things go south.

Comment: Thanks Zach, good to know. I'll make sure to grab the airside bus if my Ottawa flight is set to leave from terminal A